# WebKit browser control's DragEnter, DragOver, DragDrop events not firing in C# winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, webkit

I am using WebKit browser control in my .net winform application. However, I noticed that its DragEnter, DragOver, DragDrop events are not firing. I am trying to drop a tree view node into it.

Please help.

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Just to add into above, I have set AllowDrop property of WebKit control to TRUE.

Comment: I'm looking since a long time for a way to include a WebKit browser control in my C# app (preferable Chromium). Do you have a way to ship your complete app as a setup package, without external dependencies on WebKit/Chromium?